# In JQuery UI Tabs: how to show the selected tab after activating it via JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I'm working on a website that uses the JQuery UI Tab widget and can quite often have more tabs open than can be viewed on the screen. When this happens there is a right/left arrow to scroll through the tabs. My problem is that if I activate a new tab that isn't in view by doing `$('#tabElem').tabs("option", "active", 14)` it doesn't automatically scroll to the selected tab. I've tried doing `$('#tabElem').tabs("refresh")` but this doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that removing a non-existent tab did what I wanted to do and scrolled to the selected tab.

`$('#tabElem').tabs("remove", 99)`

Answer (score 0):

I'd get the position of the active element and window.scrollTo() it.

```
var pos = $('#tabElem').tabs("option", "active").position();
window.scrollTo(pos.left, pos.top);
```

Comment: There was a couple of things wrong with that for me. `$('#tabElem').tabs("option", "active")` just returned the position, I had to use `$('div[id="tabElem"] ul .ui-tabs-active')` to get the active tab (i'm using jQuery 1.9). Also using `window.scrollTo` didn't work. I guess I'd need to find a scroll function on the tab bar but I'm not sure there is one.